# spring-data-rest spring-data-jpa doesn't save child entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Just a simple OneToOne mapping, unidirectional.

Entities

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"})
@Data 
public abstract class ID implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity(name = "gencontractor")
@Table(name = "gencontractor")
public class GenContractor extends ID {

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Address address;
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@PersistenceConstructor))
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity(name = "address")
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address extends ID {

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String street;

    @Column
    private String city;

    @Column
    private String phone;
}
```

Table Address has PK of "id". Table GenContractor has PK "id" and foreign key "address_id" to Address.id.

Repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "gencontractors", path = "gencontractors")
public interface GenContractorRepository extends JpaRepository<GenContractor, UUID> {
}
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "addresses", path = "addresses")
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, UUID> {
}
```

When I POST /gencontractors {"email: "bla", "address": {"name":"bla", ...}}, address is not saved to Address table.

What I am missing?

Comment: You missed the inverse side of the relationship. Add @OneToOne(mappedBy="address") GenContractor genContractor to Address class, in order to specify the owning side of the relationship is GenContractor class.

Comment: @thanhngo Yup I already tried that, didn't work. That would just make it bidirectional vs unidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

Address is **NOT** an embedded object, so you cannot write it's properties directly via the parent object.

You need to create the object in two steps:

1. POST /address {"name":"bla", ...}
2. It returns with a link to the newly created object -> http://.../gencontractors/X. You need to use this link as an address:
3. POST /gencontractors {"email: "bla", "address": "http://.../gencontractors/X"}